# TextButton padding changing with Android version

Tags: android

I have been developing an app over the past few months getting ready for publication. Everything was looking just perfect. I was doing a few things with text in buttons - using my own 9-patch button backgrounds, changing the default font, repositioning textbuttons with setX() and setY() etc. I had some big buttons and smaller ones. Some were a tight fit amongst other objects on the screen, but it all worked, the buttons looked perfect on a variety of tablets and phones.

Then I remembered one last thing on my todo list which wast to change the android:minSdkVersion in my manifest from 8 up to 11. I needed to do this because the setX and setY methods are only available on android 3.0 and higher. But as soon as I did this, the text within my buttons was all screwed up. For a start it was white instead of black - easily fixed. But also the padding round the text was completely different. Buttons were now overlapping each other and looking unbalanced in a variety of ways.

So my question now is this: Is there any way to say "this software must only run on Android 3.0 (api 11) and above" AND "let all the text button characteristics be set to whatever that were with api level 8".

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why such things would happen - but it's better to just support the older platforms if you can help it. For example, if the only thing keeping you from using API 8+ is the `setX()` and `setY()` methods, you can use `ViewHelper` in the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) project to do this and support the lower API. For example:

```
ViewHelper.setX(myView, myXValue);
ViewHelper.setY(myView, myYValue);
```

Comment: I'm confused... NineOldAndroids appears to be all about animation - but the myTextButton.setX() method is just permanently setting the position of a TextButton... is that somehow animation?

Comment: @Mick, I did not realize you were using `x` and `y` animations. In that case, as long as you are using *property animations*, you can use *NineOldAndroids* as a drop-in replacement that supports API 8+. So if you add the library to your project's build path, just delete the imports of `ValueAnimator`, `ObjectAnimator` and `PropertyAnimator` and import the classes of the same name from *NineOldAndroids*.